# PHP Showing different files when switching from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, https, smarty, redirect

this is my first time asking here I hope somebody can help me.

I'm working on an application that requires to switch from HTTP to HTTPS when the user is going to check out. I'm using Smarty. The problem comes when I redirect from using this:

if I do a die() it shows the URL with HTTPS but when I redirect it shows a different file (From Smarty) but if I change HTTPS to HTTP and redirect, it works...

Can somebody help me? I'm lost and I have been trying for days!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your HTTPS files in a different folder? It is pretty common...

Comment: Might also help if you showed us an example.

Comment: What @Darren says: This is probably more a web server configuration issue.

Comment: If Apache, check the DocumentRoot in SSL's VirtualHost (extra/http-ssl.conf by default) and make sure it is pointing where you expect it to.

Comment: Well, there is no HTTPS folder around. I'm going to contact the hosting to see what happends, but if it's solved, when I switch with PHP is not going to be a problem right?